# How to find the first unique item in a list of values in a dict python 3.4

Tags: python

Hello all I have a dict

```
dat = {
       '2018-01':['jack', 'jhon','mary','mary','jack'],
       '2018-02':['Oliver', 'Connor','mary','Liam','jack','Oliver'],
       '2018-03':['Jacob', 'jhon','Reece','mary','jack'],
       '2018-04':['George', 'jhon','mary','Alexander','Richard'],
}
```

I want the output like this:

```
    Output = {
              '2018-01':['jack','jhon','mary'],
              '2018-02':['Oliver', 'Connor','Liam'],
              '2018-03':['Jacob','Reece'],
              '2018-04':['George','Alexander','Richard'] 
}
```

I have my code which is a nested for loop inserting it to a list

```
lis = []
for key,value in dat.iteritems():   
    for va in value:
        if va not in lis:
            val = key,va
            lis.append(val)
```

But my dict "dat" has so many items in the values in that list. How can I do this with out nested for loop its consuming a lot of time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this cannot be done in a unique way in Python versions prior to 3.7 where order in dictionaries is guaranteed. What version are you using? Are you assuming order in your dict?\

Comment: EDIT: Judging from the `iteritems` you are using Python 2.7 so what you are trying to do **cannot be done** in a reproducable way.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis OrderedDict ?

Comment: the casting of `dat` to `OrderedDict` would also be arbitrary. One would have to start with an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Also why is `Oliver` twice in the desired output?

Comment: Sorry I removed it. It was by mistake

Comment: Thanks. I do not get the question. And I'm not alone obvoiusly... :-) So were all those equal resulting answers right or wrong...?

Comment: Thanks @SpghttCd I have a dict of values which are not unique. and there are different keys in my dat. Now if a value is present in a list and make sure I remove the duplicates from my dict with out nested for.

Comment: And which key should be saved? the one with the earliest date?

Comment: yes where we encounter the value for the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is this:

```
dat = {
       '2018-01':['jack', 'jhon','mary','mary','jack'],
       '2018-02':['Oliver', 'Connor','mary','Liam','jack','Oliver'],
       '2018-03':['Jacob', 'jhon','Reece','mary','jack'],
       '2018-04':['George', 'jhon','mary','Alexander','Richard'],
}

unique = set()
res = {}
for key, values in dat.items():
    res[key] = []
    for value in values:
        if value not in unique:
            res[key].append(value)
            unique.add(value)
```

which produces:

```
{'2018-01': ['jack', 'jhon', 'mary'], 
 '2018-02': ['Oliver', 'Connor', 'Liam'], 
 '2018-03': ['Jacob', 'Reece'], 
 '2018-04': ['George', 'Alexander', 'Richard']}
```

---

## BUT

the order in dictionaries prior to Python version 3.7 could not be guaranteed and this makes the above code **dangerous**. The reason that is, is that with the same input you might end up having multiple different outputs.

To understand why take a look at this:

```
list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
list2 = ['bar']
```

1. If I use `list1` to eliminate all duplicates I would end up with:

   ```
   list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
   list2 = []
   ```
2. If I use `list2` to eliminate all duplicates I would end up with:

   ```
   list1 = ['foo', 'foobar']
   list2 = ['bar']
   ```

So depending on what I start with I end up having different results. With the `dict` from your example, what `list` you start with is *any man's guess*.

---

## There is still hope however

because you can **start** with an `OrderedDict` (from `collections`):

```
dat = OrderedDict([('2018-01', ['jack', 'jhon', 'mary', 'mary', 'jack']), 
                   ('2018-02', ['Oliver', 'Connor', 'mary', 'Liam', 'jack', 'Oliver']), 
                   ('2018-03', ['Jacob', 'jhon', 'Reece', 'mary', 'jack']), 
                   ('2018-04', ['George', 'jhon', 'mary', 'Alexander', 'Richard'])])
```

and then continue with the rest of the code as before.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer I'm using python 3.4 x

Comment: Then your code which you posted in your question (which btw returns a list, not a dict) does not run, as dicts have no `iteritems` in Python3 ...

Comment: I mean I just pasted a snippet but end output I was looking for a dict

Comment: and if you don't want to change the format of `dat` you can write `ordered_dat = OrderedDict(sorted(dat.items()))` and then call in the first line `for key, values in ordered_dat.items():`. So you don't need to manually change dat if you have it already written.

Answer (score 1):

Another take on @Ev. Kounis's approach using sets and `OrderedDict` (and `pprint` for sake of pretty printing):

```
import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict

dat = OrderedDict({
    '2018-01': ['jack', 'jhon', 'mary', 'mary', 'jack'],
    '2018-02': ['Oliver', 'Connor', 'mary', 'Liam', 'jack', 'Oliver'],
    '2018-03': ['Jacob', 'jhon', 'Reece', 'mary', 'jack'],
    '2018-04': ['George', 'jhon', 'mary', 'Alexander', 'Richard'],
})

exist = set()
output = OrderedDict()

for k, v in dat.items():
    output[k] = set(v) - exist
    exist.update(v)

pprint.pprint(output)

# OrderedDict([('2018-01', {'mary', 'jack', 'jhon'}),
#             ('2018-02', {'Connor', 'Oliver', 'Liam'}),
#             ('2018-03', {'Jacob', 'Reece'}),
#             ('2018-04', {'George', 'Alexander', 'Richard'})])
```

Comment: Should I convert my dict into an ordered dict ?

Comment: @user9538877 If you want reproducible and predicable results.

Comment: Does looping over the sorted keys of the dictionary have the same effect?

Comment: @DanielMesejo if it results in the order you want to have them, yes.

Comment: But you could choose any order by using the key parameter, I don't understand why someone downvoted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
l=[]
for k,v in dat.items():
    dat[k] = list(set([i for i in v if i not in l]))
    l = l + v
```

now `dat` will be:

```
{
    '2018-01': ['jhon', 'mary', 'jack'],
    '2018-02': ['Oliver', 'Liam', 'Connor'],
    '2018-03': ['Jacob', 'Reece'],
    '2018-04': ['George', 'Alexander', 'Richard']
}
```

Comment: This works but the order is not guaranteed sometimes it starts with `2018-04` and other times at `2018-01` so the output varies constantly, but it will print unique names for sure.

Comment: Yes, this just need to change `dat` to the `orderedDict`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind about the order in the list of values this can be a solution.
Note the outpout of this solution may be different according to the version of Python. Indeed dict are guaranteed to be insertion ordered only from Python3.6.

```
dat = {
'2018-01': ['jack', 'jhon', 'mary', 'mary', 'jack'],
'2018-02': ['Oliver', 'Connor', 'mary', 'Liam', 'jack', 'Oliver'],
'2018-03': ['Jacob', 'jhon', 'Reece', 'mary', 'jack'],
'2018-04': ['George', 'jhon', 'mary', 'Alexander', 'Richard'],
}

s = set()
d = {}
for k,v in dat.items():
    d[k] = list(set(v) - s)
    s.update(d[k])

#{'2018-01': ['jack', 'jhon', 'mary'], '2018-02': ['Connor', 'Oliver', 'Liam'], '2018-03': ['Reece', 'Jacob'], '2018-04': ['Richard', 'Alexander', 'George']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need, I just edit your code

```
dat = {
       '2018-01':['jack', 'jhon','mary','mary','jack'],
       '2018-02':['Oliver', 'Connor','mary','Liam','jack','Oliver'],
       '2018-03':['Jacob', 'jhon','Reece','mary','jack'],
       '2018-04':['George', 'jhon','mary','Alexander','Richard'],
}

lis= dat.values()
lis = list(set([item for sublist in lis for item in sublist]))
out_val = []
for key,value in dat.iteritems():   
    res = []
    for i in value :
        if i in lis :
            res.append(i)
            lis.remove(i)
    out_val.append(res)

your_output=dict(zip( dat.keys(), out_val))
```

Output :

```
{'2018-01': ['jack', 'jhon', 'mary'], 
'2018-03': ['Jacob', 'Reece'], 
'2018-02': ['Oliver', 'Connor', 'Liam'], 
'2018-04': ['George', 'Alexander', 'Richard']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order is by the keys `['2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03', '2018-04']` you could loop over the keys in that order, like this:

```
d = {'2018-01': ['jack', 'jhon', 'mary', 'mary', 'jack'],
     '2018-02': ['Oliver', 'Connor', 'mary', 'Liam', 'jack', 'Oliver'],
     '2018-03': ['Jacob', 'jhon', 'Reece', 'mary', 'jack'],
     '2018-04': ['George', 'jhon', 'mary', 'Alexander', 'Richard']}

result = {}
found = set()
for i in sorted(d):
    result[i] = list(set(d[i]).difference(found))
    found.update(d[i])

for i in sorted(result):
     print(i, result[i])
```

**Output**

```
2018-01 ['mary', 'jhon', 'jack']
2018-02 ['Oliver', 'Liam', 'Connor']
2018-03 ['Reece', 'Jacob']
2018-04 ['Alexander', 'Richard', 'George']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
tmp_list1 = []

for key,value in dat.iteritems():

    tmp_list2 = []

    dat[key] = list(set(value))

    for val in dat[key]:

        if val not in tmp_list1:

            tmp_list2.append(val)

    dat[key] = tmp_list2

    tmp_list1 = tmp_list1 + tmp_list2

print dat
```

Comment: did you try running that?

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
for i in d:
     d[i].sort()
     d[i] = list(i for i, _ in itertools.groupby(d[i]))

# Print the dict containing unique lists for keys.
for i in d:
     print(i, "->", d[i])
```